# How to detect in regex all sorts of hyphens, minus and dashes?

Tags: regex

Hyphen, figure dash, en dash, em dash, horizontal bar and hyphen-minus: I want to have a regex expression to detect any one of these separators (character representing an horizontal central line).

Till now I got this:

```
/[\-\–\—\−\―]/
```

but I don't know if it is robust enough and btw, I wanted to have with the character codes, to avoid changing the character upon some copy-paste conversion.

Comment: You can simply use `[\p{Pd}]` if your regex engine supports it.

Comment: @PoulBak can you give me some link explaining it?

Comment: @PoulBak your answer should be the accepted answer, please do kindly reply downwards and I set it as accepted answer

Comment: please consider also `/\p{Dash}/u`

Answer (score 2):

Finally found:

```
[\u002D\u058A\u05BE\u2010\u2011\u2012\u2013\u2014\u2015\u2E3A\u2E3B\uFE58\uFE63\uFF0D]
```

Got the codes from [here](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/category/Pd), but I just used, as stated in the question, the single horizontal lines

[image]